# How can I force my C# app to acknowledge TCP datagrams without delay?

Tags: .net, tcp, tcpclient

I tried using TcpClient.NoDelay = true, but it still doesn't send back the acknowledge until 200 ms later. I changed the network adapter's Windows registry settings to disable the Nagle algorithm, and that worked, the ACK gets sent immediately.  Shouldn't there be a way to disable the 200 ms delay without changing registry settings?

**Update**: Thanks for the suggestions about UDP. I agree that UDP is the correct protocol for the application, but unfortunately I am dealing with a device that only has a TCP interface at the moment, so my hands are tied there.

Answer (score 2):

ACK packets are a matter of inner workings of the underlying operating system's TCP/IP stack. Your app should not be anyhow harmed by the standard behavior of the TCP protocol. If yes, you should consider using something else like UDP.

Answer (score 1):

NoDelay doesn't do what you think it does.  It disables the Nagle algorithm, which is an optimization that waits a small amount of time if a full packet has not been queued to send to reduce the number of packets sent.  It has nothing to do with acknowledgement.

If you want to send packets without delay, then use UDP.  TCP has to wait for acknowledgement to know if it has to resend packets or not, and it is a safety mechanism to prevent the buffers from overflowing and losing data.

EDIT:

Upon re-reading your question, it seems that your question was a bit misleading.  If disabling nagle in the adapter works, then that means that your problem is that the packet isn't *SENT* right away, not that the acknowledge isn't coming back right away.  The ack is returning right away, it's just that the delay in sending is the problem.

Are you setting the NoDelay option after you have opened the socket or before?  Are you checking the status of NoDelay after you have set it to ensure that it was set?  Setting it to true may fail, in which case it remains false even after you set it.

Comment: You are probably right about me understanding Nagle wrong. I changed the TcpAckFrequency in the registry, which made the ACK's get sent right away.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just found it and while I *completely* agree with this statement:
"ACK packets are a matter of inner workings of the underlying operating system's TCP/IP stack."

I wholeheartedly disagree with this statement:
"Your app should not be anyhow harmed by the standard behavior of the TCP protocol."

If only that were true! Isn't the default behavior of a TCP socket that TCP_NODELAY is off, and TCP_QUICKACK is also off? AFAIK this is the case on all the platforms I've developed, please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Think about the case where a client breaks up a service request into multiple small packets. The server is waiting for more after the first packet before it will ACK because quick ack is disabled and it thinks waiting is going to be an optimization. "Surely more is coming, right? I'll just ACK multiple packets at once after they arrive!". But the client is waiting for the ACK before sending more because tinygram prevention - aka nagle's algorithm - is disabled and the next packet is well below the max payload. Therefore it depends on the nature of your app whether or not it is harmed, but certainly some apps are harmed by incurring an additional RTT worth of latency. The application layer isn't perfectly decoupled from the network layer. Now imagine the application in question is making an HTTP request. Sure, you could say it shouldn't split up its request, and yet it is not invalid to do so and the underlying network layer is now causing you harm. It's not exactly an option to switch to UDP in that case either. Also, as a somewhat hilarious aside, some UDP libraries implement their own version of tinygram prevention and enable it by default (eg. RakNet).

Lastly, sorry I don't have enough rep to comment so this is an answer :'( But since it's an answer, my actual response would have been to check if you can enable quick ack via C#'s equivalent of WinSock's setsockopt. Definitely do that on client and server if you can, and if not receiving timely ACKs is an issue. If you don't want to wait for any amount of outbound buffering then disabling tinygram prevention is probably the right move, though it may cause other side affects. Certainly you will have to live with adding TCP/IP header overhead to each payload no matter how small. Lastly, always use a packet sniffer to see what exactly is happening so that you are trying to fix only what's broken.

References:
John Nagle's response to basically the problem I have outlined above
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10607422